# Checkout: How to redirect back to cart after customer logged in within the onepage checkout process?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, login, magento-2.1

in the default onepage checkout, an existing customer can choose to login within the checkout process. this fires the usual observers. my module is observing the event sales_quote_merge_before to check if a persistent cart quote is being merged into the current quote. if so, the customer should be redirected to the /checkout/cart page.

this works fine for non-checkout pages. but setting the `setBeforeAuthUrl` and/or `setAfterAuthUrl` on the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` object does not seem to work for logins within the checkout process.

here's my (simplified) observer that works for non-checkout logins, that I now need to make work with the checkout login as well:

```
namespace My\Module\Observer;

class SalesQuoteMergeBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context
     */
    protected $_context;

    /**
     * SalesQuoteMergeBefore constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * redirect to cart when quote was merged
     *
     * @see \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::merge()
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $target */
        $target = $observer->getData('source');
        if ($target && $target->hasItems())
        {
            $url = $this->_context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl('checkout/cart');

            // setting just the after_auth_url does not seem to be enough...
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeAuthUrl($url);
            $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($url);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

my understanding is that I somehow need to signal the javascript app a redirect should happen, but I failed to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Ajax\Login::execute()` function checks for a `login_redirect` cookie. if there's such a cookie, its value will be returned as the json attribute `redirectUrl`, which in turn `Magento_Customer/js/action/login.js` uses as a redirect target after the successful login.

so faking the cookie is a simple way to control where the user should be redirected when logged in through the checkout ajax login. the relevant updated part of the observer in the question:

```
$request = $this->_context->getRequest();
if ($request instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http && $request->isAjax()) {
    // fake redirect cookie
    /** @see \Magento\Customer\Controller\Ajax\Login::execute() */
    $_COOKIE[\Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect::LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL] = $url;
} else {
    // setting just the after_auth_url does not seem to be enough...
    $this->_customerSession->setBeforeAuthUrl($url);
    $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($url);
}
```

one could also get the instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect` and use `setRedirectCookie($url)`, but I did not want to actually set a cookie in the response as the login at this point was already completed successfully.